# The URL 'shared documents/test.pdf' is invalid but file exists

Tags: sharepoint-designer, error, xslt, edit-form

Background:

1. I followed this article http://www.kraftkennedy.com/blog/bid/101982/Creating-Edit-Item-Forms-for-Document-Libraries-in-SharePoint-Designer-2010
2. I did not delete any of the fields yet
3. The new editform2.aspx is set to default
4. I upload a file ~100 kb and editform2.aspx takes my data entry and everything works
5. I upload a file ~7+ MB and editform2.aspx takes my data and upon save I get following error. Can anyone please suggest a fix?

Browser Error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<nativehr>0x81020030</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>The URL 'Shared Documents/test.pdf' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: <nativehr>0x81020030</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>The URL 'Shared Documents/test.pdf' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[COMException (0x81020030): <nativehr>0x81020030</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>The URL 'Shared Documents/test.pdf' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bPreserveItemUIVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback) +420

[SPException: The URL 'Shared Documents/test.pdf' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.UpdateCallback(Int32 affectedRecords, Exception ex) +24356681
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Update(IDictionary keys, IDictionary values, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +4065620
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.FlatCommit() +312
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.HandleOnSave(Object sender, EventArgs e) +24
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SaveButton.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +727
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +70
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

ULS Log:
Totally false error. We have nothing but space. and following error does not happen with large file when using EditForm.aspx

SqlError: 'The transaction log for database 'Content_DB' is full. To find out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases'    Source: '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' Number: 9002 State: 4 Class: 17 Procedure: 'proc_UpdateDocument' LineNumber: 428 Server: 'SPDataServer02'

Comment: is this pdf file stored on the file system or in a library/list?

Answer (score 1):

The SQL error is your real problem as once the transaction log fills up, SharePoint starts acting very strangely.  You need to [truncate the log](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/01/truncate-transaction-logs-of-sharepoint.html) and then rerun your tests.